# Loop Function Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am newbie in javascript, I want to do looping normally use "for". I would like to duplicate this script about 10 ...
how loop this script?

```
function getComboMotif1() {
    $.get("file.php?opt1=" + $("#id1"), function (data) {
        $("#asd1").html(data);
    });
}
```

The manual Loop script like this !!

```
function getww1() {
    $.get("file.php?opt1=" + $("#id1"), function (data) {
        $("#asd1").html(data);
    });
}

function getww2() {
    $.get("file.php?opt1=" + $("#id2"), function (data) {
        $("#asd1").html(data);
    });
}

function getww3() {
    $.get("file.php?opt1=" + $("#id3"), function (data) {
        $("#asd1").html(data);
    });
} //and further
```

Comment: I'd say use a counter, and call the same function again

Comment: do you want the `$.get` to run in series or parallel?

Comment: @JaromandaX parallel... my only issue in the loop, the loop parameter name getww1, getww2...>>>getww10

Comment: Why you want 10 different JS function for this. Instead of that go for single "funtion getww(number) " and pass required integer value like 1 to 10 while calling it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that :

```
function getResource(which) {
    $.get('file.php?opt1=' + $('#id' + which), function (data) {
         $('#asd' + which).html(data);
    }
}

for (var i = 0, max = 3; i < max; i += 1) {
    getResource(i);
}
```

But your code contains a few oddities.

- `$('#id1')` is a jquery object, so it can't be sent to the server as a string.
- If you always replace the `$('#asd1').html(data)` in each callback, it will get overwritten each time you get an answer from the server. That's why I made it dynamic also.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to just run through a `forloop`, then start at `1` in order to accommodate your name and id.

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
        $.get("file.php?opt1=" + $("#id" + i),    function (data) {
            $("#asd1").html(data);
    });
```

Now since `get` is asynchronous, each one will not wait for the other to complete.

---

If you need each function to be created, `getww1` and such, then I recommend using `eval` to create those functions for you. But, that is very inefficient to do and should be avoided unless there is a specific requirement. Ex:

```
...
eval("(function () { return function "
     +fname+" (){"+
     codeAsString
     +"};})()"));
...
```

That will return the newly created function.

I hope this helps to some degree.